# how to substitute variable value in url

Tags: python, url

I am trying to include variable value into url

```
ip= sys.argv[1]
    
https://management.azure.com/Subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/{ip}/backupProtectedItems?api-version=2019-05-13&
```

but when i print url i am getting like below as it is ip is not substituting

```
https://management.azure.com/Subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/{ip}/backupProtectedItems?api-version=2019-05-13&
```

can some one please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you're using Python >= 3.6 and trying to use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals), you need to prefix your string literal with `f`, like this:

```py
ip="11.22.33.44"

s = f"url/with/{ip}/and/stuff" #notice the f before the opening quote
print(s)
```

Output:

```
url/with/11.22.33.44/and/stuff
```